# python: generate 2D array from dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, numpy-ndarray

Is there an easier/shorter way to fill up `numpy` array from dictionary?

```
def build_matrix(states, n):
   M = np.zeros(shape=(n, n), dtype=np.float64)
   for key, val in states.items():
       M[key] = val
   return M
```

`states` here is a result of `Counter()` method from `collections` module, and it is basically a `dictionary`.

Example:

```
states = {(0, 1):1, (2, 2):2, (0, 2): 2}
build_matrix(states, len(states))
```

Comment: A minor change, `M[key]=val` should work, since key is already a tuple.

Comment: Can you share some example input/output?

Comment: @hpaulj, yes indeed. Thank you.

Comment: @AMC, I updated my question, and edited it with changes suggested by hpaulj

Comment: what about a CSR matrix. You can use the indices and data as numpy arrays by pulling them from your key:value pair and it will generate the matrix for you.